# How the generic return types is identified, the public static final <T> List<T> emptyList() example

Tags: java, generics

In the `Collections.java` class is present the following method:

```
public static final <T> List<T> emptyList() {
    return (List<T>) EMPTY_LIST;
}
```

I was wondering how the type T is defined! Usually the type parameter is used in the method parameter, and I can imagine that at Compile time, T is replaced, based on the parameter used. Example:

```
public static final <T> List<T> returnList(List<T> list) {
    return list;
}

...

List<String> list = ...;
Collections.returnList(list); // I know that it returns a List of string, since list is defined to contain String elements.
```

but how T is inferred here:

```
Collections.emptyList(); // It returns a list, but how T is inferred?
```

Comment: At runtime `T` does not exist, generics are a compile time only thing. In your last snippet it most likely will be `Object` but what does it matter anyway since the list is lost.

Comment: Do you mean the case where `Collection.emptyList();` is the entirety of the statement, and the result is not assigned to a variable or anything, etc?

Comment: Generics are compile time  checks. The javac just verifies that used arguments, return values and variables types are matching. The bytecode itself is unaware of generics.

Comment: Yes. I suppose that if it is assigned to a variable T depends on the variable used. Example: ‵List<String> strings = Collections.emptyList();‵ 'T' is replaced with 'String'.

Comment: No, `T` is "replaced" with nothing / `Object`. I will simply be `List strings = Collections.emptyList();'`

Comment: You cannot assign a list of `Object` to a list of `String`. Indeed `List<String> strings = Collections.emptyList();` works.

Comment: For the last time: at runtime there is no such thing as `List<String>`, at runtime there is only `List`. You can argue all you want and reject that info, will not change it though.

Comment: Forgot to mention the term: It is called type erasure.

Comment: Simone, you are correct. The compile time checks are based on the type of the variable that the expression is assigned to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Chapter 18](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-18.html) of the JLS for the exact process of type inference. Notably in this case, practically no expressions participate in type inference, and only the type parameters of the methods do. So the most relevant part that you need to look at is the end of [§18.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.1.3):

> When inference begins, a bound set is typically generated from a list
> of type parameter declarations P1, ..., Pp and associated inference
> variables α1, ..., αp. Such a bound set is generated as follows. For
> each l (1 ≤ l ≤ p):
>
> - If Pl has no TypeBound, the bound αl <: Object appears in the set.
> - Otherwise, for each type T delimited by & in the TypeBound, the bound αl <: T[P1:=α1, ..., Pp:=αp] appears in the set; if this results
>   in no proper upper bounds for αl (only dependencies), then the bound
>   αl <: Object also appears in the set.

For `Collections.emptyList`, the type parameter `T` has no bound, so the first case applies. Now `T` has an upper bound of `Object`. Then this is resolved, and another bound that says `T = Object` is incorporated, according to [§18.4 Resolution](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.4), and so, `T` is inferred to be `Object`.

In general, (oversimplifying the JLS) for a statement of the form `f();` where `f` is generic method with type parameter `T`, all the bounds of `T` (let's call them B1...Bn) gets added (as proper upper bounds) to a bound set. That bound set is resolved to the greatest lower bound ([glb](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10)) of B1...Bn, and that is the inferred type.

But alas, this doesn't really matter practically though. The type parameters are all erased at runtime. So although the spec says all of the above, in reality the compiler could very well be implemented to not do any type inference at all when it sees:

```
Collections.emptyList();
```